# Using Koin for Ktor-Client in Android: Missing type 'io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine'

Tags: ktor, koin, ktor-client, android-koin

I could use some help understanding why this module for a ktor client fails -

```
fun provideKtorClient() = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}

val ktorModule = module {
    single { provideKtorClient() }
}
```

```
@Test
    fun checkKtorModule() {
        ktorModule.verify()
    }
```

A simple test fails with the error -

`org.koin.test.verify.MissingKoinDefinitionException: Missing type 'io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine' for class 'io.ktor.client.HttpClient' in definition '\[Singleton:'io.ktor.client.HttpClient'\]'`

I tried creating an `HttpClientEngine` provider following the error message. However, this led to chasing even more objects and providers down the rabbit hole. My impression was that objects like ktor's `OkHttp` shouldn't need any further initialization. This makes me think I'm missing something larger here? Thanks!

#### EDIT / Answer

When writing a simple unit test, the extra types need to be provided for initialisation like so -

```
@Test
fun checkKtorModule() {
    ktorModule.verify(
        extraTypes = listOf(
            io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine::class,
            io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig::class
        )
    )
}
```

If running an Android instrumentation test, these classes load fine with no other specification needed -

```
@Test
fun checkAllModules() {
    koinApplication{
        modules(appModule, ktorModule)
        checkModules(){
            withInstance<Ordering.Context>()
            withInstance<Application>()
            withInstance<SavedStateHandle>()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work by providing the dependencies for the `HttpClient`'s constructor but I'm not sure if this is a right way to do it.

```
fun provideKtorClient() = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}

val ktorModule = module {
    single { provideKtorClient() }
    single<HttpClientEngine> { OkHttp.create() }
    single<HttpClientConfig<OkHttpConfig>> { HttpClientConfig() }
}

@Test
fun checkKtorModule() {
    ktorModule.verify()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding all the necessary classes! In the end, the issue ended up being my understanding of koin tests, rather than koin modules themselves.